# How can I find a GPS location using services?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm not sure how to find a current GPS location using services.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, I will show few of them:

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //TODO:location change handling
    }
}
```

Also you can use LocationOverlay:

```
 final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        overlay.enableMyLocation();
        overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
             //TODO: update some model, etc
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog that details how to get a users location and provides sample code for you.

http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/android-location-services/

Hope it helps!